# Twitter integration for ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, authentication, oauth

My application have the functionality to login via twitter and Facebook , Can any one suggest any sample code which does the same ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: have you seen facebook's developer's page? They have native iOS examples: developer.facebook.com. Also iOS6 has native support, integrates easily. there are many examples. Twitter is even easier, since everyone and their mother's have written a twitter-enabled app.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the following links,

Twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html
https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Facebook:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/Scrumptious